# onAuthStateChanged for token refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using the Javascript Firebase SDK to authenticate my users and it is working fine for the "normal" sign-in/sign-out process. 
Now i also have an open socket connection and REST-Api calls which depend on the validity of the auth token. Sadly it seems like the `onAuthStateChanged` function is not called when the token is expiring.

My `onAuthStateChanged` callback function is defined like this:

```
  Auth._onAuthStateChanged = function() {
    var that = this;

    return function(oUser) {
      // We can extend the User Object with values we need or want.
      if (oUser && !that._oUser) {
        that.onFirebaseSignIn(oUser);
      } else if (oUser && that._oUser && oUser.uid !== that._oUser.uid) {
        that.onFirebaseUserChanged();
      } else if (oUser && that._oUser && oUser.uid === that._oUser.uid) {
        that.onFirebaseTokenChanged();
      } else if (!oUser) {
        that.onFirebaseSignOut();
      }
    };
  };
```

Now something similar is working fine in Android and correctly notifies me if the token is expiring. 
Defined like this:

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && AccountTools.getCurrentUserId() == null) {
            onFirebaseSignIn(firebaseAuth);
        } else if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null &&
                AccountTools.getCurrentUserId() != null &&
                !AccountTools.getCurrentUserId().equals(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
            onFirebaseUserChanged(); // This may be the same as just signIn!
        } else if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null &&
                AccountTools.getCurrentUserId() != null &&
                AccountTools.getCurrentUserId().equals(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
            getAuthToken(false);
        } else if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            onFirebaseSignOut();
        }
    }
};
```

Is the behaviour of the `onAuthStateChanged` callback not well enough defined to rely on this? If not. What are my options? I need a valid token everytime i do a REST call and would really like not have to rely on always calling `getToken()` before doing any REST call and would rather have it to be asynchronous to everything else. Thanks!

Comment: The token does not automatically refresh unless you are using realtime db or you call getToken() when the token is expired. If you want the token to auto refresh, you have to set your own proactive refresh every hour (lifetime of the token) and call getToken(true);

Comment: I know that the token does not automatically refresh, but to my understanding firebase should notify me about the expiration of the token because it does save the expiration time internally. And this notification does work for Android (Java) but seems not to be working for Javascript.

Comment: Android and Javascript SDK should behave the same. I am not sure what you are asking for. Are you using real time database in your app? The tokens are not supposed to be announced on expiration. They are announced on refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understood this sentence inside the documenation on `onAuthStateChanged` for Android and thought it would mean that the function is called when the token expires. Instead it is only called then the token actually changes:

> When there is a change in the current user's token

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

I have this now implemented in Javascript by decoding the jwt token and then using `setTimeout` function with the expiration date. In the function called i do a forced refresh for the token.
This should make sure that the token is always valid.